# how to pass a date from my react component to an async function (for use in an API call)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a date from my react component to an async function so that the async function can change the date used in its API call.

To be more specific:
From the ChooseDate.js(aka react hook component), I am trying to call the function GetPhoto() in MarsData.js(aka the async function).

This code is then exported and used by another file that uses useState to display the API info on a webpage using REACT.

The date is not changing the API calls date, whats wrong?
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ChooseDate.js

```
import './ChooseDate.css'
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import GetPhoto from '../../APIs/MarsData';


function ChooseDate() {

    const [data,setData] = useState(null)
    const [print,setPrint] = useState(false)

    function getDate(val){
        //setPrint(false)

        setData(val.target.value)
        GetPhoto('2022-10-17')
        console.log(val.target.value)
    }

    return(
    <form action="/space-vision/public" method="get">
    <div classname = "App">
        {
        print?
        <h1>{data}</h1>
        :null
        }
      <input type="text" onChange={getDate}/>
    </div>
        <button onClick={e=>{
            e.preventDefault(),
            setPrint(true)} }className='SearchButton'>Submit </button>
    </form>)
}
export default ChooseDate;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

MarsData.js

```
async function GetPhoto(val){
  
    let path = '/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?';
    let earth_date= 'earth_date=2022-08-10&'     //use format:'earth_date=[date]&'
    let camera= ''           //use format: camera=[string]&
    let page = ''            //use format: page=[int]&
    let api_call=path + earth_date + camera + page;

    
    if (val!=null)
        earth_date='earth_date=2022-10-17&';
        
        //'earth_date='+val.toString()+'&'
    

    const APIKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
    let response = await fetch('https://api.nasa.gov' + api_call + 'api_key=' + APIKey );
    let data = await response.json();

    console.log(data);

    return data;

}

export default GetPhoto;
```

---

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you want the `val` passed in the GetPhoto function to change the api call `earth_date` parameter?

Comment: thats right, i know the code shows a hardcoded date being passed rather than val, but thats just for now incase there are small errors while passing. ill change that to show val later

Answer (score 0):

Your `api_call` variable is defined before you're checking if your `val` is null. If you assign your `earth_date` after the if statement it will update if val is not null.

```js
if (val != null) earth_date = "earth_date=2022-10-17&";

let api_call = path + earth_date + camera + page;
```

If you want to use your `val` in the future you can wrap it in backticks

```js
if (val != null) earth_date = `earth_date=${val}&`;

let api_call = path + earth_date + camera + page;
```

Hope this helps you with your project